# Tikz: foreach loop - How to increment index by 1?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I use `tkz-euclide` to shift a point like this

```
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A1](1,0){A2}
```

Let's say I want 7 points next to each other. I can do something like

```
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A1](1,0){A2}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A2](1,0){A3}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A3](1,0){A4}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A4](1,0){A5}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A5](1,0){A6}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A6](1,0){A7}
```

Is there a shortcut for this situation?

**What I've already tried**

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[A\i](1,0){A{\i+1}}
}
```

...but the `{\i+1}` part results in an error.

**Workaround**

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \edef\indexnew{\fpeval{\i + 1}}
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[A\i](1,0){A\indexnew}
}
```

This does the job, but I think there is an easier solution.

Comment: Try `\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[A\i](1,0){A\the\numexpr\i+1}
}` or `\foreach \i [count=\j] in {2,...,7}{
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[A\j](1,0){A\i}
}`

Comment: Your second solution doesn't work if I want to shift for example only the points ´A3´ to ´A6´. Or is it posible to give ´[count=\j]´ a different start value?

Comment: Yes, you can use `[count=\j from 3]`, say.

Comment: I searched the `tikz` and the `tkz-euclid` manual to learn more about `[count=...]`. I couldn't find anything. Is it even possible to set several of this counters? Something like `[count=\j from 3,\k from 6]`?

Comment: You can find it on p. 1004 of pgfmanual v3.1.5.

Comment: Is it even possible to combine your two solutions into one? Something like `foreach \i [count=\j from {\i+1}]`?

Comment: You can always try out and the answer is yes: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
{\foreach \j [count=\k from \i+1] in {1,2,3}
{\i,\j,\k\par}}
\end{document}`.

Comment: I really like the `[count=\j from \i+1]` solution, but it throws an error in my case. It says `! Undefined control sequence.\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ \foreach \i [count=\j from \i+1]`.

Comment: The solution with `\numexpr` is fine but possible is `\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,...,6}{ \tkzDefShiftPoint[A\i](1,0){A\j} }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my various comments above.

1. You can use `\numexpr`.
2. You can use `evaluate` with `int`.
3. You can use `count=<variable> from <start>`.

This list is not exhaustive and apart from `\numexpr` you can find these things in section **89 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement** of pgfmanual v3.1.5. Notice that one has to be careful when using `parse` with integers, which is why I did not add it to the list.

These are just some examples and interestingly the last one also works, but without braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
{\i,\the\numexpr\i+4\relax\par} %<- sometimes one needs a \relax to delimit
% the numexpr stuff from other expressions that could be parsed

\bigskip

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {int(\i+4)}] in {1,...,5}
{\i,\j\par} 

\bigskip

\foreach \i [count=\j from 5] in {1,...,5}
{\i,\j\par} 

\bigskip

% if you want to start from an expression, do not add braces 
% i.e. no braces around \i+1
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
{\foreach \j [count=\k from \i+1] in {1,2,3}
{\i,\j,\k\par}}


\end{document}
```

`tikzmath` has some very closely related yet somewhat different options.

Please note that there is also the good old `\loop` which does not put the stuff it is iterating over in groups (which one can replace by `\pgfmathloop` in the pgf context). Also pgfplots offers `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, which avoids grouping, too. More information can be found in section **8.1 Utility Commands** of the pgfplots (!) manual v1.17. This can be instrumental for defining stuff only *locally* (which is less relevant for the example in the question, though).

And there are many more loop routines from `expl3`, `listofitems`, `etoolbox` and I am sure I forgot many. Each of them has some particular strengths (and sometimes also weaker points).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the `evaluate` functionality of the `foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   %%% modification according to comments; thanks for pointing it out
   \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ieval using {int(\i+42)}] in {1,...,6} {
      \node at (\i,0) {\ieval};
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is precisely how one should not do it here. This will add `.0` at the results. *If* you want to do that, use `\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ieval using {int(\i+42)}] in {1,...,6} {
      \node at (\i,0) {\ieval};
   }` but I do not really see any advantage compared to the comments above.

Comment: +1 Without `{int(\i+42)}` this solution throws an error in my case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. @Schrödinger'scat The advantage is that it is very flexible, e.g. as an alternative for shifting A3 to A6 (as OP asked in comments). My answer uses another approach and the `evaluate` syntax comes in quite handy in many cases. And there's another advantage, of course: this is an answer, while comments are just... comments. :)